# Publishing my asp.net mvc web application using VS 2012 on IIS is not working, unless I run the web application inside the VS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-6

I have an asp.net mvc 4 web application , and I use the visual studio publish feature,  to publish my web application to the localhost iis. But currently if I type the web application URL it will not work unless I open the VS and run the application. so can anyone adive how I can publish my web application on IIS so users can access the web application event if the VS is not running .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Publishing a website to your Inetpub\wwwroot is not recommended on a standard computer, you will need to host your application on a server. Windows server has no limit on the amount of connections allowed to your webpage, whereas your computer can only handle a maximum of 10 connections.

if you want your solution to work outside of VS but still on your computer, you will have to create a virtual directory within IIS or within VS (then VS will do it in IIS for you).

Right click on your project, go to the "web" tab, there is an option there to host it within IIS and a button that creates the virtual directory for you.

Also check that you then have an application pool set up and running the correct version of .NET (depending on the framework you created the application in)